# Setting HttpOnly in JBoss 7.1.1 throws error

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, servlet-3.0, httponly

I migrated my `web.xml` to `3.0xsd` and added the following code to set cookies to HttpOnly

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <http-only>true</http-only>        
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

but I get an error while deploying the project in JBoss

```
Failed to parse XML descriptor "/C:/Amber/My_Server/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments/Project_Test.war/WEB-INF/web.xml" at [187,1]
```

[187,1] refers to the line number in `web.xml` where the `session-config` part begins.

Is session-config not supported in `JBoss 7.1.1`? I got the code I used from a similar question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I've just deployed a web app with session-config that you provided without any errors. Could you post some more details?
   When you specify:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0"
```

in your web.xml and get rid of servlet-api-2.5 from your classpath everything should be fine.

Comment: I had changed the version web.xml already. Tried replacing servlet-api.jar with servlet-api-3.0.jar but it still didn't work...:-(